# Adding a field to attribute table and populating using a list

Tags: arcpy

I have four folders, each with 50 sub folders.  Within each sub folder I have 80 shapefiles.  For the first shapefile within each sub folder I want to add a field and populate that field with the name of the sub folder.

I am attempting to do this like so:

```
import arcpy
import os

folders=r'F:\Sheyenne\grazing_final\pressure_per_pixel_by_allotment\allotment_points' #path to four folders
for folder in os.listdir(folders):


    for sub in os.listdir(os.path.join(folders,folder)): #path to sub folders

        arcpy.env.workspace=os.path.join(folders,folder,sub)  #set environment
        shapefiles=[os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, i) for i in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')]
        shapefiles=shapefiles[0] #return only the first shapefile from each sub folder

        arcpy.AddField_management(shapefiles, "Allotment", "SHORT", "5") #add new field to each shapefile

        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefiles, 'Allotment') as cursor: #populate each field with the string contained in sub
        for row in cursor:
            row.setValue(sub)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        del row
```

but this returns:

```
 File "F:/python codes/prelim_codes/grazing_regression.py", line 78, in <module>
    row.setValue(allotment)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'setValue'
```

Comment: You don't have 78 lines in your code snippet, yet your error refers to `line 78`, and a line of code that I can't see in your snippet.  Have you tested your snippet as posted above, and what error do you get from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your indent is wrong in your `with` - the `for` line should be indented further (and also the lines contained within the `for`).  Also you don't need to `del row` if it's contained within the `with` block.

You appear to be mixing code from two types of Update Cursors.  With the `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` your `row` is returned as a list of fields values which you can update using `row[0] = x` etc.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefiles, 'Allotment') as cursor: #populate each field with the string contained in sub
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = sub
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

So in the code here each record has the value of `sub` written to the `Allotment` field.  It will be the same value written to every record in your shapefile.